# Building String Matches From Subsets In Python

Tags: python-2.7

I have a solution to my problem using itertools permutations, but for use cases bigger than my example it is computationally expensive.

Basically I start with a sentence as string, simplified:

`a = "a b c d"`

Through a different process I then get a list of subsets of the string, eg:

`suba = ["d","c d","b c d","a b","b c","a b c","a"]`

The result I want is a list of combinations that from suba that can be joined to make a, eg:

`[('a b', 'c d'), ('a b c', 'd'), ('a', 'b c d'), ('a', 'b c', 'd')]`

I produced the above with brute force using permutations as below, is there a less computationally expensive approach?

```
import itertools

a = "a b c d"
suba = ["d","c d","b c d","a b","b c","a b c","a"]

combos = []


for i in range(len(suba)):
    p = itertools.permutations(suba,i)
    for j in p:
        if ' '.join(j) == a:
            combos.append(j)

print combos
```

Comment: hint: number of words in `a` is 4. No need to try permutations with 5 elements or more because it produces always wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

first generate the combinations, as there are less combinations than permutations this is faster. only if the string length is correct are the various permutations of that specific combination generated.

```
def stringmatch(a, suba):
    combos= []
    for i in range(len(suba)):
        p = itertools.combinations(suba,i)
        for j in p:
            if len(' '.join(j)) == len(a):
                q = itertools.permutations(j, len(j))
                for r in q:
                    if ' '.join(r) == a:
                        combos.append(r)
    return combos
```

using the given example string and substrings, this method takes 0.061 ms versus 2.023 ms for your approach. The margin should grow as the number of substrings increase